# can't find variable: x - looping through an array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to iterate through an array stored in the store.
I get this red box error: `can't find variable: city.`
Is this a correct way to loop through an array in reactJS?

```
class CitiesPage extends Component {

  render() {    
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Cities Info:</Text>
        <div>
          {this.props.citiesArr}.map(function(city) {
            <li key={city}>{city}</li>
          });
        </div>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My array inside the store looks like this:

```
const STORE_STATES = {
    citiesArr: [
        {city:'Rome', population:'34454'},
        {city:'Paris', population:'45678'}, 
        {city:'London', population:'2334'},
        {city:'Milan', population:'23456'},
        {city:'Amsterdam', population:'1234'},
        {city:'Dublin', population: '234'},
        {city:'Valencia', population: '2345'},
        {city:'Ankara', population: '3456'}
    ]
};
```

Comment: I think this.props.citiesArr.cities doesn't exist. The array is citiesArr itself, am I wrong? Oh, I see you edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
{
  this.props.citiesArr.map(function(city) {
    <li key={city}>{city}</li>
  })
}

// or ES6 arrow function
{this.props.citiesArr.map((city) => <li key={city}>{city}</li>)}
```

Instead of

```js
{this.props.citiesArr}.map(function(city) {
  <li key={city}>{city}</li>
});
```

---

In JSX (that code that looks like HTML but actually isn't), JavaScript has to be between `{ }` and you misplaced the second one. Babel most likely transpiles your JSX into a code that does something totally different and causes the error. Check the transpiled source code if you're not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
{
    this.props.citiesArr.map((city) =>
        <li key={city}>{city}</li>
    );
}
</div>
```

Javascript is written inside jsx using { [your javascript code] }.